# Find the slidelayout in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, layout, powerpoint, slide

I am trying to figure out if a specific custom layout is in my presentation.
I want to use this to create a slide with a TOC that lists the slides with this specific layout.

After some searching and trying I got this far, but it aborts on the below bold item, any suggestions :

```
Sub ShowSlideLayouts()

  Dim oSlide As Slide
  Dim idSlide As String
  Dim oLayoutName As String
  Dim sFileName As String
  Dim iFileNum As String

  sFileName = "C:\temp\PowerPointLayouts.TXT"

  iFileNum = FreeFile()
  Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum

  For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    idSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.***SlideID*** <-- wrong method/member

    'Print #iFileNum, oSlide.Layout
    Print #iFileNum, ActivePresentation.Slides(idSlide).CustomLayout.Name
    'Print #iFileNum, ActivePresentation.Slides.getAttribute("layout")
    'For Each oLayoutName In ActivePresentation.Slides().CustomLayouts.Name
    'MsgBox ActivePresentation.Slides(idSlide).CustomLayout.Name
        'Print #iFileNum, oLayoutName.Id & vbTab & oLayoutName.Caption
   ' Next

 Next

  Close iFileNum

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all that mess with idSlide; oSlide gives you a reference to each slide in the presentation, so:

```
For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    Debug.Print oSlide.CustomLayout.Name
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, works. <br/> ' iFileNum = FreeFile()
  Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
  For x = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    With ActivePresentation
      Print #iFileNum, .Slides(x).CustomLayout.Name & vbTab & .Slides(x).CustomLayout.Index
    End With
    Next
  Close iFileNum '

Comment: Sorry for the wrong formatting, tried it, but now system gives me a 5 minute warning.

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean that the code works but SO won't let you reformat.  In other words, all ok, right?

Comment: Yes it does Steve.  <br/> Now figuring out how to get 1 specific layout to count and then make it available for the TOC.